# Django model foreign key or onetoone?

Tags: django, model

I have 3 table in my project, the first one is the default user table os django with username password, firstname and last name filds
the second one is the userprofile and third is stocks .

the user table is for saving data of both sellers and buyers.

```
class Stocks(models.Model):
  user=models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
  name=models.CharField(max_length=128,verbose_name=_('stockname'))
  number=models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=64,verbose_name=_('number'))
  brand=models.CharField(max_length=64, validators=[
    RegexValidator(regex='^[A-Z]*$',message=_(u'brand must be in Capital letter'),)]
    ,verbose_name=_('brand'))
  comment=models.CharField(blank=True,null=True,max_length=264,verbose_name=_('comment'))
  price=models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True,verbose_name=_('price'))
  date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True,verbose_name=_('date'))
  checking= ((_('pending'),_('pending')),
       (_('reject'),_('reject')),
       (_('approved'),_('approved')),
       (_('expired'),_('expired')),
            )
  confirm=models.CharField(choices=checking,max_length=12,verbose_name=_('confirmation'), default=_('pending'))
  def __str__(self):
      return str(self.name)
  class Meta:
    verbose_name=_('Stock')
    verbose_name_plural=_('Stocks')
  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('BallbearingSite:mystocks' )


class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
  user=models.OneToOneField(User,related_name='profile')
  phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\d{11,11}$', message=_(u"Phone number must be 11 digit."))
  cellphone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex],  max_length=17,verbose_name=_('cellphone'))
  tel = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=17,verbose_name=_('tel'))
  state=models.CharField(validators=[farsi_regex],max_length=128,verbose_name=_('state'))
 city=models.CharField(validators=[farsi_regex],max_length=128,verbose_name=_('city'))
 address=models.CharField(validators=[farsi_regex],max_length=264,verbose_name=_('address'))
 def __str__ (self):
    return self.user.username

 class Meta:
    verbose_name=_('UserProfileInfo')
    verbose_name_plural=_('UserProfileInfos')
```

the buyer can choose stocks to buy which the seller has sent.
so in my fourth table, i should have seller id, buyer id and stock id  which refers to the user table and the stock table . 
i want to know which field should be defined as onetoone and which one as foreign key ? and how can i define that it refer to id of the user and id of the stock in their table ?

I wrote this model :

```
class SellerDesktop(models.Model)
 seller=models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='seller')
 buyer=models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='buyer')
 stock=models.ForeignKey(Stocks)
  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.seller) + '-' + str(self.buyer)
  class Meta:
    verbose_name=_('SellerDesktop')
    verbose_name_plural=_('SellerDesktop')
```

but in the admin panel i can choose stock only by their name but i want to choose id of each stock which is unique becouse eache name has different brand and each brand has different number and i can not choose only by name

Answer (score 0):

In your stock model, you can add an id to output with the name. something like this and then you can pick stock by id and name.

```
 def __str__(self):
      return str(self.id + ' - ' + self.name)
```